# Why does my Promise reducer pattern mess up the order?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've implemented my calls to the back-end for this tiny part of my system with `Promises` using the `reduce()` pattern as such:

First of all, a helper object that deals with AJAX calls using promises:

```
class Base_Ajax_Requester extends Promise_Helped_AJAX_Call {
    ajax_success(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    ajax_error(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

It has the `call` function which basically returns a promise with whatever the AJAX call has returned. I can then use `Base_Ajax_Requester.call().then()` to hook up to when it's done with that call.

My current form of the system is that first I download a schema file, then a few import files:

```
let fake_data = {
    'demo_handle' : 'demo-2',
    'steps_to_import' : [ 'post', 'elementor-hf' ]
}

function install_items_original() {
    let demo_schema_download = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
        localized_data.ajax_url,
        {
            //data
        }
    );

    let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(function(previous_promise, next_step_identifier) {
        return previous_promise.then(function() {
            let download_import_files_promise = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
                localized_data.ajax_url,
                {
                    //data
                }
            );
            return download_import_files_promise.call();
        });
    }, Promise.resolve())).catch( function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    return import_files_download;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Sometimes it gets confused and it calls the `download_import_files_promise` instead of `demo_schema_download` first. Or worse yet, **it doesn't wait for the first promise, `demo_schema_download`** to finish.

Yet, if I do virtually the same thing, but hard-coded:

```
function install_demo_hardcoded() {
    let demo_schema_download = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
        localized_data.ajax_url,
        {
            //data
        }
    );

    let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
        let download_import_files_promise_1 = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
            localized_data.ajax_url,
            {
                //data
            }
        );
        download_import_files_promise_1.call().then(function() {
            let download_import_files_promise_2 = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
                localized_data.ajax_url,
                {
                    //data
                }
            );
            download_import_files_promise_2.call();
        });
    });

    return import_files_download;
}
```

What exactly is it I'm missing? I'm smelling improper error handling for the first Promise at `demo_schema_download.call().then(..)` where I should handle the case where it actually fails and not call the next 2. On the other hand, I've checked the case it fails and it doesn't proceed. Alternatively, this works too:

```
function install_demo_original() {
    let demo_schema_download = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
        localized_data.ajax_url,
        {
        }
    );

    let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
        let download_import_files_promise = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
            localized_data.ajax_url,
            {
            }
        );
        download_import_files_promise.call().then( function() {
            let download_import_files_promise = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
                localized_data.ajax_url,
                {
            });
            download_import_files_promise.call();
        });
    });

    return import_files_download;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit!

When I'm calling the `.then` on my initial call of `demo_schema_download.call()`, I am straight up passing a `reduce` to it: `fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(...` when I should be passing a `function` with that reduce in it:

```
let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
        fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(function(previous_promise, next_step_identifier) {...
```

Making the final code look like:

```
let import_files_download = demo_schema_download.call().then(function() {
    fake_data.steps_to_import.reduce(function(previous_promise, next_step_identifier) {
        return previous_promise.then(function() {
            let download_import_files_promise = new Base_Ajax_Requester(
                localized_data.ajax_url,
                {
                    //data
                }
            );
            return download_import_files_promise.call();
        });
    }, Promise.resolve())
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Naturally, this looks like a monster, but, hey, Javascript, right?